# HTC. infinite reboot. How to turn off bluetooth from adb?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, htc, reboot

I have rooted HTC Evo 3d with android 4.0.1
Today i turn on bluetooth and my phone went to infinite reboot. Nothing helps!
I think there is only one way to turn off bluetooth - ADB.

I tried use this commands, but it was useless:

```
adb shell su -c service call bluetooth_manager 8
adb shell su -c service call bluetooth 4
```

Please help me turn off bluetooth!

Comment: 1) Give us the result of `adb shell service list` because I'm not convinced that you've bluetooth_manager service. 2) Where did you learn those commands? Link it. The second command enables bluetooth in my device. In my Android 4.2.1, `bluetooth 5` and in Android 5.0.2 `bluetooth_manager 10` disables the bluetooth. The integer refers to a function and that  would most likely differ between Android versions. // Anyhow, in both of my Android versions, setting `bluetooth_on` to 0 in table global of settings.db followed by a reboot works well to disable bluetooth.

Comment: Try this, `adb shell su -c settings put global bluetooth_on 0` or `adb shell content update --uri content://settings/global --bind value:s:0 --where "name='bluetooth_on'"`, reboot, and tell us the result.

Comment: First command give me:
`sh: settings: not found`
Second command:
`/system/bin/sh: content: not found`

After DOS'ing my phone throw adb by `adb shell su -c service call bluetooth 4` command it's turning off bluetooth

Comment: IF your rom and/or busybox version contains rfkill applet/binary try running `rfkill block bluetooth`