# HTC one infinite reboot. How to turn off bluetooth from adb?

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, bluetooth, htc

This is my first question here...

My problem is similar to the one explained here:

[HTC. infinite reboot. How to turn off bluetooth from adb?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/132522/htc-infinite-reboot-how-to-turn-off-bluetooth-from-adb)

..my HTC one rebooting continuously due to bluetooth. So I need to turn bluetooth off from adb or other.
I don't have any experience with adb/fastboot nor with recovery mode. I have a Mac with Android Studio installed (including SDK and adb+fastboot). (I'm only starting to learn "android programming").

I would like to try the commands posted in the above link to solve my issue but I have some problems:

To enter the Recovery-mode menu I pass through the "Recovery" option on the boot menu (see image).
[image: HTC boot menu]
In the HTC site they list the options available on the Recovery-mode menu. The options of this menu are the same I have when I enter recovery-mode, except that there should be an "Apply update from ADB" option that is not present on my phone. (see picture)
[image: HTC recovery mode menu]

I know adb installation is correctly set up (I use it to connect to my other phone to test the app I develop on Android Studio).

I know that my mac can "see" my HTC when it's connected to USB (for a short moment, before rebooting, when the Android UI of my phone has already load, my mac shows me a message - from Android File Transfer application - telling me that it can't connect to the device).
[image]
[image: File Transfer message]

When I'm in recovery mode and I connect my phone through USB and I enter the ADB command "adb devices" on my terminal and my HTC phone is not listed.

Do you think I have any chance to fix this problem ? I'd like to avoid factory resetting my phone.

Any help/guidance on how to operate would be very much appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: What recovery have you installed (e.g. TWRP)? Stock recovery has no UI options nor adb connectivity. If your device is still locked you have to unlock it which erases all user data. In such a case it would be better to try to use adb on the regular OS in the time span before it reboots.

Comment: Thanks Robert for your answer. When I speak about "recovery menu" I mean the recovery-mode on my phone. I have no recovery software installed neither on my MacBook nor on my phone.
The time span before it reboots is minimal.
I will re-edit the question adding some images, maybe it will be easier to understand (as english is not my mother tongue, I may not be clear enough)

Comment: As I wrote this stock recovery has no ADB functionality.

Comment: thanks again. I didn't know what you meant by "stock recovery".
As I wrote, there's no time before the phone restarts to connect on regular OS.
Is there any chance to recover my data before unlocking ?